# Получить ключ и значение из массива. Функции ES5

Tags: javascript

Дан массив со значениями фруктов

```
var fruits = [{name: "banana", count: 2}, {name: "orange", count: 10}, {name: "apple:, count: 3}]
```

Как из этого получить ключ-значение по типу

```
banana : 2
orange : 10
apple : 3
```

используя функции ES5

Comment: ответ дан но почему именно es5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var fruits = [
  {name: "banana", count: 2}, 
  {name: "orange", count: 10}, 
  {name: "apple", count: 3}
];
var a = fruits.reduce((r, i) => (r[i.name] = i.count, r), {});
console.log(a);
```