# Прикрепить нумерацию к добавляемым строчкам в таблице jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы в добавляемых строчках в таблице соблюдалась нумерация.

То, что я написал:

```
table.html("<td><span class = 'index'></td>");

table.each(function (i) {
            $(this).find(".index").text(i + 1);
        });
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1217576

Comment: да, извиняюсь, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var table = $('table');
table.append("<tr><td><span class='index'></td></tr>");
table.append("<tr><td><span class='index'></td></tr>");
table.append("<tr><td><span class='index'></td></tr>");

table.find("tr").each(function(i) {
  $(this).find(".index").text(i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1></table>
```

Comment: спасибо, но не совсем то

Comment: @hajime Добавьте в вопрос больше кода/html. А лучше - сделайте работающий пример. Ссылка "править" под вопросом. Кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.